# show img when hovering (only if hover had a delay of 2 seconds)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I want my users to be able to hover a post title in my blog, and if they hover the title for 2 seconds, the image will show.

I am trying something like:

```
$('#post1').hover(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#img1').toggle();
  }, 2000); 
});
```

But it's not working as expecting. It keeps toggling after the initial 2s hover. How would you do it?

Comment: change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`, the first one make the function repeats for ever and the second one (setTimeout) run the function one time after the delay.

Comment: `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, first of all. But I think jQuery has a `.delay()` function…

Comment: I tried setTimeout, but even if you hover for 1 ms, the image will show after the specified delay (2000ms).

Comment: I would take a look at http://furnish-hospitality.com/resources/scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timeoutId;
$("#post1").hover(function() {
    if (!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            timeoutId = null; 
            $("#img1").toggle();
       }, 2000);
    }
},
function () {
    if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
    }
    else {
       $("#img1").toggle();
    }
});
```

Here is some working code and a [jsfiddle to prove it works](http://jsfiddle.net/4jxKk/)

Answer (score 0):

.delay() is a great way to do it as well:

```
 $('#post1').hover(function() {
   $('#img1').delay(2000);
   $('#img1').toggle();
 });
```